# Angular / NGX Bootstrap component - add attribute to last item only

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have a dynamic list that uses NGX Bootstrap Dropdowns to display 4 sets of dropdown lists.  The  Dropdowns in the last list get obscured off-page.  NXG Bootstrap offer a **dropUp** option for such situations. So i want to apply to the *final item only*

Heres what the loop to insert the components looks like:

**filter-builder.componet.html**

```
 <div *ngFor="let settingsService of _settingsServices">
        <filter-builder-item [settingsHelperService]="settingsService"></filter-builder-item>
    </div>
```

and inside the component:

**filter-builder-item.componet.html**

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown [dropup]="isDropup">
    <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;">
            <i class="la la-save"></i>Update</a>
        </li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;">
            <i class="la la-save"></i>Save</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div
```

How can I add the [dropup]="isDropup" to the last instance of the component only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `last` in `*ngFor`, like this:

**filter-builder.component.html**:

```
 <div *ngFor="let settingsService of _settingsServices; last as last">
   <filter-builder-item
     [settingsHelperService]="settingsService"
     [dropup]="last"></filter-builder-item>
 </div>
```

**filter-builder-item.component.ts**:

```
@Input() dropup: boolean;
```

**filter-builder-item.component.html**:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown [dropup]="dropup">
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;">
      <i class="la la-save"></i>Update</a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:;">
      <i class="la la-save"></i>Save</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3mqlh)

Comment: Hi developer033, thanks for the response.  Im sure youre on the right track. But  what is the reason you changed [dropup]="isDropup" to  [dropup]="dropup"?
I dont think we can change that, because it part of the NGX Bootstrap syntax.  Are you able to repost your answer using isDropup please?
(I tried to reformulate it, but without success!).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @swisstony `isDropup` is just a variable name, man :). Of course you can change that, but it's up to you. And yes, it works. I've created a demo for proof and edited the answer above with it. Btw it seems that you're missing the `dropdownToggle`?